# What is the nature of this function in the interval $(-1,4)$

Tags: calculus, continuity, maxima-minima

Consider the following function

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \left|x\right| & \quad x <2\\
            \lfloor x\rfloor & \quad x \ge 2
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

where $\lfloor\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function. For $x \in(-1,4)$ I need to analyze which options are true ?

(a) $f$ has a local maxima

(b) $f$ has a local minima

(c) $f$ is continuous

(d) $f$ is not differentiable

So, option (c) is false as the greatest integer is discontinuous at integral points.

option (d) is correct as $|x|$ is non differentiable at $x=0$ also , $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is non differentiable at integral points.

(b) Is correct because $f(0-) > f(0)$ and $f(0) < f(0+)$ so $f$  has a local minima at $x=0$

Option (a) also seems to be correct  because

for $x \ge 2$ $f = \lfloor x\rfloor$ and

$f(3-) = 2$ while $f(3) = f(3+) =3$ so  $f(3-) < f(3)$ and $f(3) \ge f(3+)$
so $x =3$ is one such point of local  maxima.

So, according to me options (a) (b) and (d) are correct.

However, my  book says correct choices are (b) and (d)

Can anyone please explain why is option (a) incorrect ? and what is wrong with my solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is right. c) is false and a), b) d) are all true.

Comment: At $x=3$ no peak is formed.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri It is still a local maximum. All you need for a local maximum at  is that $f(x)\le f(3)$ for an open interval containing 3. The inequality does not have to be strict (for $x\ne3$). It may seem odd, but a constant function has a local maximum at every point.